# User context per request dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am looking at creating a user context per request. Something like this, but it just feels wrong:

```
container.Register<UserContext>(() =>
{
     var context = new UserContext();
     //add runtime data...                   
     return context;
});
```

And then inject it into a base service layer class for reuse.

Can anyone point me in a better direction to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction of object graphs should be [reliable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), so we can construct them [with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/). This basically means that [we shouldn't construct them using runtime data](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

`HttpContext` and its properties are runtime data, and accessing it during object graph construction:

> ***causes ambiguity, complicates the composition root with an extra responsibility and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration.***

The solution is to refactor `UserContext` in such way that `HttpContext` is only accessed when one of its members (other than the constructor) is accessed. This allows the `UserContext` to be constructed without knowledge about the request and even allows it to become stateless and singleton. The [referenced](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) article shows an example of such implementation:

```
class HttpSessionUserContext : IUserContext 
{
    public int CurrentUserId => (int)HttpContext.Session["userId"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Steven, that makes things clear and the article looks straight to the point. Perfect answer.